# Grok with Logstash - Invalid character

Tags: logstash-grok

I have the following message:

> [Thu Nov 01 21:54:03 2012] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] File não not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/default/cpc

That uses the `Grok` filter as below:

> ^[(?%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR})]\s+([%{WORD:loglevel}]\s+)?%{GREEDYDATA:message}

The problem is that in the `{GREEDYDATA:message}` block the `Grok` parser is replacing the character `ã` to `�`.

Any idea of what happened? It's running on a Windows Server.

Comment: Have you made sure this isn't a [charset](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/plugins-codecs-plain.html) problem?

Comment: Yes. The Logstash Input session is a UDP with a charset 1252 and if I remove the Filter session where I use grok and write the message in a file in the Output session, it's being done properly, but when grok Is added in the filter, the behavior is the one stated above. Find the complete sample:input{
   udp{
      port => 5140
      codec => plain {
         charset => "CP1252"
      }
      type => "log4net"   
}